# Inverting logarithmic output from VAR model

Tags: forecasting, vector-autoregression, logarithm

I'm working on a VAR model and am doing a log transformation of the raw data.

```
x = log(x)
```

After differencing, running various tests and running a VAR(2) model, I add the predicted differences cumulatively to the original time series (logged) like this:

```
prd.diffs <- as.ts(prd$mean$d.x1)
U <- tail(undiff,2)
cumu <- cumsum(prd.diffs) + U[1]
```

However, while the output now looks as it should, it is still in logged values.

**My question is as follows:**

How does one return the logged output to original values? I'm under the impression that using `exp()` will not give the correct results, and having tried some variations it hasn't worked for me.

Does the fact that it is a VAR($p$) model (and possibly what lag it has) influence the method, and how should that be implemented to get the correct output?

*P.S. I realise that the above code does not constitute a replicable example as I didn't deem that necessary for the question, but should that be desired I can add some more code.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual question seems to be, if one has an optimal (say, in mean-square sense) forecast $\widehat{\log(x)}$ of $\log(x)$, is $e^{\widehat{\log(x)}}$ an optimal forecast of $x$?

The answer is generally **no**.

Here is Dave Giles' excellent blog post ["More on Prediction From Log-Linear Regressions"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2014/12/s.html) explaining the issue and suggesting a remedy -- the smearing estimator of Duan (1983) (the details are a little tedious but they are explained very well in the said blog post).

In a *special case* where the errors in the model for $\log(x)$ are normally distributed, the optimal (in mean-square sense) prediction of $x$ is

$$ \hat x^* = e^{\widehat{\log(x)}} + \frac{\hat\sigma^2}{2} $$

where $\hat\sigma^2$ is an unbiased estimator of error variance from the model for $\log(x)$. However, this result is sensitive to normality and should be used with care.

Now the good news for an applied forecaster: there is some evidence that empirically the simple way of exponentiating the prediction $\widehat{\log(x)}$ may be superior to using the formula given above for the case of Normal errors -- once specification and estimation uncertainty are taken into account; see Bårdsen & Lütkepohl (2011).

**References**

- Duan, N., 1983. Smearing estimate: A nonparametric retransformation method. *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 78, 605-610.
- Bårdsen, G., and H. Lütkepohl, 2011. Forecasting levels of log variables in vector autoregressions. *International Journal of Forecasting*, 27, 1108-1115.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! A naive forecast seems to fit pretty well.

Comment: You are welcome! I was happy to find the article by Bårdsen and Lütkepohl myself since it provides some consolation for choosing the simple solution and saves some coding time.