# First difference in logs transformation produces biased results on back-transformation

Tags: data-transformation, logarithm, numerics, back-transformation, bias-correction

I have a strongly trended series where the trend appears to be exponential and I believe the errors tend to be proportional to the current value. In order to convert it to a stationary series for purposes of forecasting, I expected to do the usual difference in logs transformation. However, it seems that changes have to be really tiny, or else you get a consistent bias strictly from the numerical approximation when it is transformed back into levels.

For example, if you have a three percent change from a base of, say, 100,

`log(103) - log(100) = 0.0295588`  (approximately. All calculations done with R.)

So 0.029558 would be my dependent variable in this case.
To reconstruct the value of the change, take the base, 100, times one plus the estimated change, and subtract the base from the result.

```
100 * (1 + 0.0295588) = 102.9559
(3 – 2.9559)/3 = 0.0147
```

Which is to say, a consistent underestimation by about one and a half percent, less for smaller changes, more for bigger ones.

Changes in my data are usually smaller than 3 percent, but are that high or higher in about one observation in 210. To me, this seems like a big enough bias to worry about, especially since it is largest when we forecast big changes. Is there a standard correction for this? Or a different way of doing the back-transformation that gives results that are more numerically accurate?

Comment: See our posts on the lognormal distribution (focusing on expressions of the form $\exp(\sigma^2/2)$ or, for a more general approach, see [Duan's smearing estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Duan%27s+smearing+estimator).  Whether either of these is appropriate, though, depends on your model, your data, and your intended application.  In particular, to apply the lognormal correction the model ought to posit that the random variation is (approximately) Normally distributed and the data need to be consistent with that.  Thus, you might get better answers by providing more context.

Comment: Thanks, whuber! Following your suggestion, this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201665/inverting-logarithmic-output-from-var-model/201680#201680  by Richard Hardy was an excelent and highly informative answer to my quesrtion as well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that post, Andrew.